# Can't create a table via SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2022 Developer edition on premise. I have created a new database using SQL Server Management Studio v18.12.1.

When I try to create a table, I get the following error:

[image]

If I click on "Show Details", I then see a message:

> This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables (MS Visual Database tools)

Does anybody have any idea how I get round this? Creating a table is a basic thing.

Comment: _SSMS version 19.0 is now available and is the recommended version of SSMS for SQL Server 2022 (16.x)._ Ref: [What's new in SQL Server 2022 (16.x)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2022)

Comment: Creating a table is a basic thing, and I'd strongly encourage you to learn how to do so via the `CREATE TABLE` statement. The visual designers, on the other hand, are almost always to *some extent* broken.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, I know how to script the commands, but have never come across this issue in SSMS before in all the years since SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Previous SSMS versions would simply break in interesting ways if you used them on versions of SQL Server they didn't really support, as they'd just try to muddle through. Whether that's better than doing an explicit compatibility check is debatable, but for better or worse, it's being done in this case.

Comment: As an example of long broken behaviour, the query optimizer was fixed to recognise that `TOP 100 PERCENT` doesn't require sorting; it was fixed in either 2005 or 2008. The view designer *today* still acts as if sorting is something that can be applied to views and tries to do it using that long defunct trick.

Comment: V18.12.1 was the latest release of ssms when I installed Sql Server 2022. It's only now though that I've got round to doing something with it. I have upgraded SSMS as per @AlwaysLearning suggestion and this has solver the issue. If AlwaysLearning would like to change the comment to an answer I will set it as the accepted answer.